# Google Script and Anonymous user in Google Sheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I've a public Google Sheet (everyone can access it and edit it). In it, I use a script, a function, that download a csv with the `UrlFetchApp.fetch(url);`.

When an anonymous user access it (without the google login), the user can view, and edit the sheet, but, the user cannot run the script. The user must be logged with a google account to the script do the working.

The stranger thing is that this sheet with this script was working for anonymous users early. This problem didn't occur before a couple weeks ago.

Do you know if the google change something about security or is it an error that I am doing?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Google App Script - allowing access for anonymous users](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27173605/google-app-script-allowing-access-for-anonymous-users)

Answer (score 0):

In order to run apps script on a particular user's behalf, Google Workspace requires that user's permission, via an OAuth flow.

If a user is anonymous therefore, you can see why this permission cannot be granted, which is why the script won't work for those users.

Answer (score -1):

I guess it is an intended behavior as long as the anonymous user access the sheet via shareable link. As stated in this [support page](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/2494888?hl=en), you might see a name you don’t recognize or "anonymous animals" viewing your document, spreadsheet, or presentation. **This can happen when a document is shared publicly or with anyone who has the link.**

**Limit how people can view your file**
If you want to stop sharing a file you can edit, you can learn how to:

- [Turn off link sharing for a file.](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/2494893#turn_off_link_sharing)
- [Prevent others from sharing files you own.](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/2494893#restrict_sharing)

Hope this helps.

Comment: I want this public "behavior", plus with the GS working too. Do you know how do I can goal this?