# Run Google Scripts as Anonymous

Tags: javascript, json, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a google spreadsheet which has scripts in there (with several functions) who gets the inputs from the sheet, run a flask python code and then I get a response as javascript and finally, putt the result values in the sheet.

I only can do this if I'm in my Google Account and because I'm the author.
However, I want to share the spreadsheet by a link with edit permission and when I open the spreadsheet as anonymous, I can't run the scripts! it says 'It occurred an error in the script XXX'

How can I change the permissions of the entire script in order to execute the functions of the script as anonymous?

Thank you

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Google App Script - allowing access for anonymous users](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27173605/google-app-script-allowing-access-for-anonymous-users)